# Sealing off duct work

Tags: hvac, sealing

Mice are getting in my house in a area of my home where I have ducts coming from the crawlspace through the floor up to our second floor and I would like to find a solution what can I use to seal off this entry point since ducts are flexible I can't think of anything that will bond subflooring to ducts

Comment: What sort of ducts do you have that are flexible and that mice won't chew through to get around whatever you seal the gaps with?

Comment: This is the problem with flexducts--mice, rats, possums can all chew right through them.

Comment: I agree with Jim Stewart, flex ducting is just plastic insulation and plastic with wire in the plastic to maintain its shape. Any critter can chew through given time or if they want to get inside in a short time. Metal ducting may be the only way to stop them while they live.

Comment: How are your flexible ducts currently "mounted" or secured? Can you send a photo? I agree with the other commenters that you wont stop a rodent from getting in, but perhaps you can minimize it

Answer (score 1):

The best money spent would be finding where the critters are entering the home or crawl space and sealing that access point. Changing or modifying the duct work will be a costly procedure, and the critters may still get into your living space through some other means. If you still want to seal off the flex ducts, call a local HVAC company and ask for a price to replace with metal ducting.